# Get value from exact JSONpath level

Tags: json

I want to extract values from an JSON document with using the path operators.
For example I get all the product IDs included in the file via $..product_id.
But for getting the "id" when I use $..id I get an output for each id element, no matter on which level of the JSON the variable is.
For example in my output I get an row for the id "12345678" as well as for "11223344" which should not be because it is a subset of the first ID.

```
 {
"next_offset": 20,
"records": [
    {
        "id": "12345678",
        "date": "2020-02-14",
        "product_id": "asdf1234",
        "product_name": "Product_test^_1",
        "template_link": {
            "name": "aassddff",
            "id": "11223344",
            "_acl": {
                "fields": [],
                "_hash": "345thvz356b56v456b"
            }
        },
        ....
    }
]
```

}

How can I set the path operator to only access the "id" fields of one specific level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the JSON shown in your question, use `$.records.*.id`.

Comment: Actually it's not the root level, it's like:
{
    "next_offset": 20,
    "records": [
        { 
        "id": "12345678",
        "date": "2020-02-14",
        "product_id": "asdf1234",
        "product_name": "Product_test^_1",
        "template_link": {
            "name": "aassddff",
            "id": "11223344",
            "_acl": {
                "fields": [],
                "_hash": "345thvz356b56v456b"
            }
        },
        ....

Comment: @Bryan So why didn't you post that in your question?